# Problem With Realm Saving Using Swift. By mistake, I said "Delete Object" directly From Realm Browser 0

Tags: ios, swift, realm

To test out what would happen if there weren't any categories in my realm file, I directly deleted the objects for "Categories" in the Realm browser. Now, whenever I add a new item from my app, it doesn't even register in the Realm browser.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import RealmSwift

class CategoryViewController: UITableViewController {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var categories: Results<Category>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadCategory()
    }

    // MARK: - Table View Datasource

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories?.count ?? 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryCell", for : indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = categories?[indexPath.row].name ?? "No Categories Added Yet!"
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - Table View Delegate

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToItems", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ToDoListViewController
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destinationVC.selectCategory = categories![indexPath.row]
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Data Manipulation Methods

    func save(category: Category) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(categories!)
            }
        } catch {
            print("There was an error saving context, \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func loadCategory() {
        categories = realm.objects(Category.self)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        var textField = UITextField()

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Category", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in
            let newCategory = Category()
            newCategory.name = textField.text!
            self.save(category: newCategory)
        }

        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addTextField { (field) in
            textField = field
            textField.placeholder = "Add A New Category"
        }

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When I Am Adding Something Called "Shopping" To My Categories:

[image: When I Am Adding Something Called "Shopping" To My Categories]

After I Click The Add Button:

[image: After I Click The Add Button]

My Realm Browser After I already Added "Shopping":

[image: My Realm Browser After I already Added "Shopping"]

Keep in mind, that I have added objects into the realm file before too, so even though it doesn't show up in the realm file, the "No Categories Added Yet" doesn't even show up... There is definitely some issue. I don't get any errors from the debug console.

Comment: Hey guys, I would really appreciate it if you could help me out with this.... Thanks a lot again...

Comment: Thank you Tyler for making this question more readable!

Comment: Hmmm....   See this `realm.add(categories!)` where you're saving the **empty** class var whereas it should be this `realm.add(category)`

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for helping me Jay! It works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by mistakenly you are adding "categories" into realm. In **save()** function, you just need to replace "categories" with "category".

Comment: Good catch (see my comment to the question). In general here on SO, if it's pretty much a typo or something that isn't really a coding issue/question, it's better to post it as a comment instead of an answer. An answer would usually be best suited to help future readers and looking for a typo wouldn't be that much of a help. Still a good catch ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this valuable information @Jay. But i think an answer is a good thing for future readers. Usually readers notice only two things. Firstly they notice the question and secondly they quickly scroll down to the list of answers. And if someone don't find any suitable answer then they go for the comments.

Comment: Cool. I voted to close the question as it was just a typo more than anything and probably won't be a lot of help to future readers.

Comment: No problem @Tejas